# Input Filter to restrict Special Characters & numbers

Tags: android, android-edittext, special-characters, restrict

Can any one advice me what is the best approach to add a filter for editText so that it should not allow Special Character & numbers. it should only allow "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

below is the filter which i have used currently

```
private InputFilter testFilter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                if(!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))){                    
                    if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))){
                        return "";
                    }

                }

            }

            return null;
        }
    };

editTest.setFilter(testFilter);
```

This code is restricting Special Characters but allowing numbers.

Kindly advice 
Thanks & Regards.
Nagendra

Comment: Your `if(!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i)))` is not needed.

Comment: yes that true, but still it is accepting numbers

Comment: `if(!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))){
                        return "";
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that checks if the Character is allowed and use that instead of `Character.isLetterOrDigit`.